# where does kmeans store its trained model parameters in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, machine-learning-model

Like in linear regression, there is `model.intercept_` and `model.coef_` but in kmeans i found  `kmeans.inertia_` , I dont know what is that.

Answer (score 1):

K-means stores 4 model parameters namely `cluster_centers_`, `labels_`, `inertia_`, `n_iter_`. For details on what they store you can look at the official [documentation.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) Also, Inertia, or the within-cluster sum of squares criterion, can be recognized as a measure of how internally coherent clusters are. You can see a full description [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) under the section: 2.3.2. K-means.